# Ошибки в setcookie и $_SESSION

Tags: php

1.Код

```
<body>
<?php
setcookie("name1","value");
echo $_COOKIE["name1"]
?>

</body>
```

Oшибка:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php:9) in Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php on line 10..

Проблема в настройках сервера?

2.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["ses"]=100;
    echo $_SESSION["ses"];
?>
```

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php:9) in Z:\home\localhost\www\index.php on line 10

```
<?php

include('1.php'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Документ без названия</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo $_SESSION["ses"];
?>

</body>
```

Код 1.php

<?php
 session_start();
    $_SESSION["ses"]=100;

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кукисы можно устанавливать до какого-либо вывода:

```
<?php setcookie("name1","value"); ?> // начало скрипта
<body>
<?php
echo $_COOKIE["name1"]
?>

</body>
```

Так должно работать.

Comment: Это сессию нужно вызывать до какого-либо вывода, а кукисы можно где угодно. О чем в принципе в ошибке, в 1 посте и сказано.

Comment: If output exists prior to calling this function, `setcookie()` will fail and return FALSE. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Был не прав, признаю :) Думал что это только к сессиям относится.

Comment: Всё нормально, я уже успел засомневаться))

Answer (score 0):

> on line 10

Я вот на глаз подсчитал, ну ни как там 10 строк не будет которые ты показал, ищи ниже ошибку, а код написан правильно.

Comment: Я думаю выложен кусок кода, а текст ошибки тупо скопировали.

Comment: про перевод строк слышал?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у тебя после `echo $_COOKIE["name1"]` идет установка `header();`. После вывода данных нельзя устанавливать `header()`. Ну и куки тоже устанавливать можно только до вывода контента.